# Plugin Version List not Shown

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have plugins already live on wordpress.org. One of my plugins is https://wordpress.org/plugins/raratheme-companion.

The problem is I came to realize today that I can not find the drop-down of the version list on my plugins page. That is why I am unable to download old version of the plugins. How can I have that version drop-down on my plugin? I even checked the **Advanced View**.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't tagged any versions: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/raratheme-companion/tags/

Comment: From the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/#tagging-new-versions